# Validating a series of asp.net textboxes with CustomValidator and an unique function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a group of several ASP.NET textboxes, each TB have their correspondent CustomValidator and a server-side function. It is possible to use an unique function to validate and change background color on all the textboxes?

```
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="requestLast" MaxLength="64" runat="server" />
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" ControlToValidate="requestLast" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="ValGroup" ></asp:CustomValidator>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="requestFirst" MaxLength="64" runat="server" />
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" ControlToValidate="requestFirst" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"  ValidateEmptyText="True" ValidationGroup="ValGroup"></asp:CustomValidator>

                    <asp:Button ID="submitRequest" runat="server" OnClick="submitRequest_Click" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="ValGroup" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>



    protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        //The code for validation goes here
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to reference the controls, in order to check the value and change the background color!

```
    protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        CustomValidator obj2val = (CustomValidator) source;
        TextBox ctrl = (TextBox)FindControl(obj2val.ControlToValidate);
        bool is_valid = args.Value != "";

        ctrl.BackColor = is_valid ? System.Drawing.Color.White : System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        updPanel1.Update();

        args.IsValid = is_valid;
    }
```

this checks if the control is empty, and changes background color to red if is true.